# where are the apt indexes stored and can they be removed?

Tags: apt, package-management, docker

I am performing an `apt-get update` prior to installing some packages:

```
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B]
...
...
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [40 B]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [58.0 kB]
Fetched 20.0 MB in 2min 57s (113 kB/s)
```

As can be seen above, `apt-get` has fetched 20.0 MB of indexes.  After the `apt-get update` and the `apt-get install mypackage`, I would like to clean up all caches to minimise the disk space used.

**Question 1**: Where are the apt package indexes stored on the file system?

**Question 2**: How can I safely remove the indexes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at /var/cache/apt folder. Both the index files and downloaded package files reside there. For cleanup, you can check [an older question thread here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65549/var-cache-apt-archives-occupying-huge-space)
.

Comment: The linked question does **not** address the index files directly under `/var/cache/apt` (i.e. `*.bin`). The alleged (but not in fact) "duplicate" of your link [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/223090) asks about those index files in particular, but the answers are wrong. The index files can be safely removed (as of Ubuntu 14.04, which I tested) as the next `apt-get update` will regenerate those files. The files in `/var/cache/apt/archives` can be cleaned using `apt-get clean`.

Answer (score 4):

**NB:** all of the following was tested on Ubuntu 14.04.

**Up front:** don't remove any directories, just files *inside* of the directories. Also make sure **no apt-related processes are running** (or could get auto-started *during* your cleanup).

### /var/cache/apt/archives/*

The files in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, i.e. the downloaded packages, can be cleaned using `apt-get clean`. This is the method that is linked in the other answer.

### /var/cache/apt/*.bin

As long as you ensure that no apt-related process is running the index files `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin` and `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin` can also be cleaned out. Unless they are leftover, there should not be any other files that would match `/var/cache/apt/*.bin`, but you can remove them using that pattern as long as no apt-related process is running.

The next run of `apt-get update` will regenerate these files.

Unfortunately [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/223090) asking about the index files was closed as duplicate, although it isn't a duplicate at all.

### /var/lib/apt/lists/*

You can also remove the cached package lists, but might want to leave the lock file untouched.

Yes, the file `lock` can also be removed, provided no apt-related processes are running or would start during cleanup. But I mentioned that already once or twice.

---

### Rationale

I wondered about this possibility to be able to create a template archive to use for creation of containers (LXC, Docker). In such a case you usually want to trim down the system as much as possible before packaging.

Turns out it is harmless to remove the files. In my particular case I can be sure no apt-related processes are running, as the "system" - after the `chroot` part finishes - isn't actually running.

### Potential apt-related processes

`cron-apt`, but also `unattended-upgrades` and similar would be examples apt-related processes that you don't want to run during a cleanup.

Comment: Another note: `rm -f` will *intentionally* skip the `partial` subfolders. So use that instead of a potential `rm -rf` - see my introductory remarks at the top.