# Unattended upgrade fills hard drive when there is problem with Apt source

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, updates, unattended-upgrades

My server running `Ubuntu 14.04.5 server` had its hard disk filled very quickly.

Directory `/var/cache/apt` was full of files like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 41M Mar 11 05:16 pkgcache.bin.t7Hu64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 42M Mar 11 05:16 pkgcache.bin.786Hkg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 42M Mar 11 05:17 pkgcache.bin.HYjl6J
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 42M Mar 11 05:17 pkgcache.bin.h6Hk8l
```

Few files got created every minute. After some research I found that Unattended upgades was causing this. Probably because there had been some problem with Apt-mirror.

Using `apt-get update` got erros:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch http://local.apt.mirror/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch http://local.apt.mirror/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I was able to fix this by doing `apt-get clean` on the server.

Is there way to change behaviour of Unattended upgades so that I would not fill disk with temp files when there are some problems with `apt-get update`?

It would be much better to have Unattended upgades stop at error instead of keeping going until disk is filled with temp files.

EDIT: I am not asking about `Hash sum mismatch`. I know what it is and how it can be solved. I am asking about `Unattended upgrades`.

Comment: Does not look duplicate to me. `Hash sum mistach` probably caused the problem I have, but I is not what I am asking about here.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223090/is-it-safe-to-manually-delete-the-var-cache-apt-content) answer your needs?

Comment: It is helpfull but does not offer full solution to my problem.